# Creating a class that can store a int, std::string or double in one member variable

Tags: c++

I am having to create a class which has a member variable named m_Value which is of type std::string but is supposed to be able to accept input from a user either as a double, int or std::string.

Here is this Field.h:

```
class Field 
{
public:
    Field(std::string name, std::string value);

    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetValue();

    void Print();

private:
    std::string m_Name; 
    std::string m_Value;
};
```

There is another class which has a method to instantiate this class called Element:

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element();
    void Print();

    Field* AddField(std::string fieldName, std::string fieldValue);
    Field* GetField(std::string fieldName);

private:
    std::vector<Field*> m_Fields;

};
```

What I am supposed to be able to do is allow the class method AddField() to be able to take in an int, double or std::string and have it stored in the field member variable. This would be an example scenario:

[image]

I have thought to add overloading methods for AddField but then how do I store that value since member variables have to be of one type?

Comment: [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)?

Comment: This kind of scenario is what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is good for

Comment: Use `std::variant`  or `std::any`. If you don't  have c++ 17, use `boost::variant` or `boost::any`

Comment: Yea, I just did that lol. I think writing my question made me think a bit more clear lol Thanks for taht!

Comment: Never used std::variant... ill look it up

Comment: @geza OP wrote *"I am having to create a class which has a member variable named m_Value which is of type std::string"* therefore I assumed `std::string` as given. I agree that if the type is not given, other options are better.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches:

- Store it and convert it to a string
- Use a tagged union.

The tagged union approach is probably cleaner. Before C++17 the tagged unions can be implemented with anonymous unions. With c++17 you can use variants.

Rule [182](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-anonymous) of the C++ core guidelines has a nice example.